# subtract the first column matrix from the elements from a vector

Tags: matlab

I want to write the Matlab code of subtracting a matrix with size(3,4) and a vector (1,4), how I can subtract the first column elements of the matrix from the first element of a vector.
for example:
A=[1  3  4   5;  4  8  11  7; 2  1  7   3]
B=[1  1  2  5]

C=A-B= [0  2  2  0; 3  7  9  2; 1  0  5 -2]
I appreciate any help

Comment: You literally found the solution: `C = A -B;`. This works thanks to [implicit expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/). For old Matlab versions you need `C = bsxfun(@minus, A, B);`